# Equal width and intrinsic width tables

Tags: css, layout, html-table, css-tables

All the tables in my app are designed to be the size of their content.
When there are multiple tables on a page, because they are a different width the lack of alignment looks bad.
I want to have the less wide table expand to be the width of the wider table. This is easy with a div containing both tables set to `width: fit-content` and the tables set to 100%. e.g.:

```html
<div>
<table>standard table code here</table>
<table>standard table code here</table>
</div>
```

```css
div {
width: fit-content;
}

table {
 width: 100%;
}
```

The problem is that I want any excess free space on the narrower table to appear on the right, rather than being distributed among the whole table (as [shown in this example](https://codepen.io/cssgrid/pen/jOxYrgM)).

What I would like to achieve looks something like this:

[image]

Using CSS grid this would be easy by using the `fr` unit to take up any available space ([Codepen example here](https://codepen.io/cssgrid/pen/KKRZZYQ) using CSS subgrid so does not work in Chrome yet). While I can achieve the layout I want I need to implement it with a HTML table to be semantically correct. Is this possible?

Perhaps relevant: sometimes the columns in the table will be `text-align: right`.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that the text won't need to be split on multiple lines you can set the last column width to 100% and use white-space: nowrap as below

```css
table {
  border: solid 1px #EDEEEF;
  border-collapse: seperate;
  border-spacing: 0;
  text-align: left;
  border-radius: 3px;
  width: 100%;
}

td,
th {
  padding-left: 40px;
  white-space:nowrap;
}

td:last-child {
width:100%;
}

td:first-child,
th:first-child {
  padding-left: 16px;
}

td:last-child,
th:last-child {
  padding-right: 16px;
}

thead th {
  background-color: #F7F7F8;
  color: #585858;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #EDEEEF;
}

td {
  color: #686868;
}

tr:not(:last-child) td {
  border-bottom: solid 1px #F7F7F8;
}

td,
th {
  padding-block: 8px;
}

.align-right {
  text-align: right;
}

thead th:first-child {
  border-top-left-radius: 2px;
  /* needs to be 1px less than the border-radius of the table */
}

thead th:last-child {
  border-top-right-radius: 2px;
}

tr:hover {
  background-color: #F7F7F8;
}

div {
  width: fit-content;
}

.mt-medium {
  margin-top: 24px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table class="smaller-table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Lorem ipsum</th>
        <th class="align-right">Mean</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>something</td>
        <td>something else</td>
        <td class="align-right">23</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>something</td>
        <td>something else</td>
        <td class="align-right">23</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>something</td>
        <td>something else</td>
        <td class="align-right">23</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <table class="mt-medium">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Lorem ipsum</th>
        <th>Lorem ipsum</th>
        <th>Lorem ipsum</th>
        <th class="align-right">Mean</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>something</td>
        <td>something else</td>
        <td>lorem ipsum</td>
        <td>lorem ipsum</td>
        <td class="align-right">23</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>something</td>
        <td>something else</td>
        <td>lorem ipsum</td>
        <td>lorem ipsum</td>
        <td class="align-right">23</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>something</td>
        <td>something else</td>
        <td>lorem ipsum</td>
        <td>lorem ipsum</td>
        <td class="align-right">23</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this with empty table cells in an extra column on the right set to:

```css
.spacer {
  width: 100%;
}
```

This forces the text in all the other table cells to wrap, which you can change with:

```css
th, td {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```